# Does Spark structured streaming support chained flatMapGroupsWithState by different key?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Here, by **chained**, I mean does Spark structured streaming support something like below:

```
val ds1 = dataset.groupByKey(r => r.Key1)
    .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Append(), GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(...)
val ds2 = ds1.groupByKey(r => r.Key2)
    .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Append(), GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(...)
```

I asked this question because when I try to do this, I got following error:

> Detected pattern of possible 'correctness' issue due to global
> watermark. The query contains stateful operation which can emit rows
> older than the current watermark plus allowed late record delay, which
> are "late rows" in downstream stateful operations and these rows can
> be discarded. Please refer the programming guide doc for more details.
> If you understand the possible risk of correctness issue and still
> need to run the query, you can disable this check by setting the
> config `spark.sql.streaming.statefulOperator.checkCorrectness.enabled`
> to false.

And after I disable the check, Spark app runs, but the second state function has no inputs. Which is not expected because the first state function has output when I removed the second state function.